# PHP pack and unpack feature

Tags: php, pack, unpack

When I run something like `pack('N', "123455")` or any variation of the 'N' option, I always get a character returned. The above example returns `�?`.

I am trying to work with *Clamd* and streaming to the socket and it needs "4 bytes unsigned integer in network byte order". I simply cannot get it to work.

Comment: Could you post the code you have so far?

Comment: ``` <?php
    $myint = "123455";
    $my_packed = pack('N', $myint);
    echo $my_packed;
    ?> ```

Comment: A bit of formatting

Answer (score 3):

echo'ing binary data will pretty much always output something that looks like that. Binary data is not meant to be read and understood by humans.

```
$binary = pack('N', "123455");
$hex = bin2hex($binary);
echo $hex;
// 0001e23f
```

Your `pack()` call properly returns the binary data `00 01 e2 3f` which is a 4-byte big-endian representation of the number 123455. For a number, you can verify this by converting the number to hexadecimal (`echo dechex(123455);` => `1e23f`) and prepending zeroes until you reach 4 bytes (8 hexadecimal characters, `0001e23f`).

Echo'ing the binary data will make PHP treat it as a string, with `00 01` and `e2 3f` as the characters. `0x0001` is a control character (rendered as "�") and `0xe23f` does not exist as a predefined character (it falls in the Private Use Area of the Unicode standard), so it will render as "?".

Comment: Thanks.  I just can't seem to get it to work with the Clamd streaming function.

Comment: To help you debug that, we'd need to see what you're doing and what error you're getting. The problem is not with the way you're using `pack()`, but maybe with the way you're sending it to clamd.

Comment: I figured it out.  It was the format I was sending the zero byte to signal the end of the stream.  I had to change
```
socket_send($socket, pack('N', 0),0), MSG_DONTROUTE); to socket_send($socket, pack('N', 0),strlen(pack('N', 0)), MSG_DONTROUTE);
```